# How to maximize score in Dunwall City Trials : Bend Time Massacre

Tags: dishonored

Even playing just the first 'scene' my score seems pretty random even when I kill all 4 targets. Sometimes its a few hundred, sometimes its over 2,000.

What factors affect the score awarded at the end of each 'scene'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some mind-numbing research re-re-re-replaying the first scene, here's some thoughts and numbers.

- Each kill gives 30 points
- A "Novelty" Kill gives an extra 100 (A sword kill from behind counts as novelty, not sure what else does). I think only the first novelty kill in a scene gives the bonus
- Killing all possible targets gives 500 bonus
- "Headshot" and "Fatality" also seem to give bonus, but I haven't quantified that

However, the most important effect is the score multiplier. The multiplier seems to be determined like this:-

Every kill during an explosion (grenades and oil tanks, NOT spring razors) adds 2 to the multiplier, and the score accumulated during the explosion is multiplied by this number at the end. If you have several explosions almost simultaneously, then they share a single multiplier. Any other kills occuring during the explosions (eg spring razors) also increase the multiplier.

For maximum score, you want to kill as many as possible via simultaneous explosions, and - ideally - make sure you kill the final target during the explosion to get the 500 bonus multiplied up as well.

Here's a few examples, using the first scene:-

- Kill 3 targets using pistol/springrazor (no explosions!) :
  **3 * 30  = 90 points**
- Kill all 4 targets using pistol/springrazor (no explosions!) 
  **4 * 30 + 500 = 620 points**
- Kill 3 targets using single whaletank explosion (3 targets = 6x multiplier): **6 * 3 * 30 = 540 points**.

But, to get better points, you need to do it like this:-

- Kill first target using sword **30+100 bonus) = 130**
  Then, kill remaining three using whaletank: (6x multiplier) **6 * (3 * 30 + 500) = 3540** for a grand total of **3670****